# Using Datalog by itself, is it possible?

Tags: datalog

I am currently studying Datalog for my report in class, I only need to discuss basic syntax and a basic example.

I know Datalog is usually used as a query language and is usually only implemented to other languages such as Java, Lua, C, etc. but is it possible to teach Datalog only by itself, or am I required to use another language implementing it to show a simple working program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few online demos you can use:

- http://iris-reasoner.org/demo
- http://ysangkok.github.io/mitre-datalog.js/wrapper.html
- https://repl.logicblox.com/ (docs here: 
  https://developer.logicblox.com/content/docs4/tutorial/repl/section/split.html )

I haven't tried it myself yet, but http://abcdatalog.seas.harvard.edu also looks nice and easy to run.

A complete overview is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog

Comment: Thank you! The abcdatalog program was, in fact, easy to use. The UI isn't all that great though but I feel it would be enough for some sample programming.